# Is it possible to delete a message sent in a separate channel (Discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

So what I want to do is delete a message sent in a channel other than the one the command is being sent in. What I have tried so far is

```
import discord
import os

from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

    @bot.command()
    async def Delete(ctx, amount=1):
      channel = bot.get_channel(Channel_ID)
      await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)

bot.run(os.getenv("Token"))
```

But it ignores the line

```
channel = bot.get_channel(Channel_ID)
```

Is it because the command has to be sent in the channel you want it to delete a message in?
Or is it that the command simply doesn't exist and if so is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't ignore the the channel, you simply aren't deleting in it,

```py
await channel.purge(limit=1) # Not `ctx.channel`
```

Also your indentation is wrong and you didn't import `os`